# How to set an element to the start position when the end of the scroll is reached?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider-container that has a slider-content inside it, the container is set to overflow-x: hidden; , the idea is to scroll the elements inside the slider-content to the very end of the scroll by increasing the scrollLeft, but for some reason the scrolling does not work to the end - you can clearly see this if you set the overflow value to scroll.
HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider-content">
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 1290px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
}

.slide img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

JS:

```
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
const sliderContent = document.querySelector(".slider-content");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

function main() {
  let scrollX = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    if (sliderContainer && sliderContent) {
      scrollX += 0.5;
      sliderContent.scroll(scrollX, 0);

      if (sliderContainer.scrollLeft >= sliderContent.clientWidth) {
        scrollX = 0; // this code is not reached
        sliderContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
      }
    }
  }, 5);
}

main();
```

I need it when the maximum scroll is reached element - set its position to 0. How can this be done?
Codepen:
https://codepen.io/MadnessTony/pen/jOQaWyy

Comment: Please make a snippet on your question instead of linking to your code on codepen

Comment: only some tracks... first sliderContent.clientWidth value is different than its real width. If you take "const r = sliderContent.getBoundingClientRect();", you will see the real value (1273 - 1290). Second you have overflow-x hidden but you are checking value of sliderContainer.scrollLeft. Put a console.log(sliderContainer.scrollLeft); you will see it's always 0, so code after is never reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you were expecting this kind of behaviour from the scroll.

```js
const sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
const sliderContent = document.querySelector(".slider-content");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

function main() {
    let scrollX = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
        if (sliderContainer && sliderContent) {
            scrollX += 0.5;
            sliderContent.scroll(scrollX, 0);
            var scrollRight = sliderContent.scrollWidth - sliderContent.clientWidth - sliderContent.scrollLeft;
            if (scrollRight < 1) {
                scrollX = 0; // this code is not reached
                sliderContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
            }
        }
    }, 5);
}

main();
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.slider-container {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider-content {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slide {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
}

.slide img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Web Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slider-container">
        <div class="slider-content">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://www.fool.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/dogecoin-16_9-3.jpg" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).